# Опытные программисты ответьте на вопрос пожалуйста?

Tags: веб-программирование

Изучил Pascal, хочу дальше копать в сторону web-developer. Из многообразия языков выбрал PHP, востребованный и хостингов много. Но что то не любят его, и начинать именно с него не советуют. Задал вопрос, мне ответили, что нужно почитать Струтура и интерпретация компьютерных программ. Изучить C++/C#, хотя бы базово написать пару программ на одном из этих языков, понять концепцию ООП. Ну про сервера и протоколы разумеется прочту, чтобы узнать как устроена сеть. Стоит ли так делать, учить c++ или C#, чтобы потом перейти на PHP или не стоит терять время и брать в зубы Котерова с документацией. Мне в принципе все равно, главное научиться хорошо выполнять свою работу. Все что надо изучу и прочту, не ленивый, к тому же сын родился этим мотивирован))). А то на зарплату технолога многое не купишь, а программисты в нашем городе на расхват, работа есть. И еще прочитал, про c++ средний порог вхождения, думаю долго времени уйдет на изучение фишек языка, а C# мне как то больше нравится документация есть, и мне она понятна, web достаточно часто применяется?

Comment: Заголовок должен отражать суть вопроса. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: При чем тут:

   к тому же сын родился этим мотивирован

...эх...что за люди.

Comment: Я его понимаю: при рождении дитя денежки очень нужны. И начинают мозги шевелиться...

Answer (score 1):

Вечер добрый.  ИМХО не стоит бросаться с языка на язык только для того чтобы, к примеру освоить ООП. К тому же языки из разных опер. Вникать в такой серьезный язык как С++(плюсы), чтобы написать 2-3 программы (как вы сказали) и переходить на новый точно не стоит. К тому же зачем вникать в "фишки" языка, которым не собираетесь пользоваться? Что касается PHP - в интернетах его недолюбливают, но это неплохой язык - в его *основы* легко вникнуть и начать писать, чего не скажешь о плюсах. C#(шарп) - гораздо проще в изучении, нежели плюсы, меньше тонкостей и подводных камней. НО повторюсь - для изучения PHP он вам не нужен) Программисты - это всегда полиглоты. Поверьте будет чем голову занять)

Comment: Базовых знаний pascal,наличие воли и упорства у меня есть хватит этого, чтобы писать код который будет действительно хорошим!

Comment: Базовых знаний не хватит, но большой объем практики поможет. Недостаточно написать 2 - 3 программы, нужно писать все время и много. Выберите себе задачу и решайте её, возникают конкретные вопросы ищите в гугле или спрашиваете на форумах. Так же советую посмотреть список требований для кандидата и параллельно учить их.

Comment: Паскаль показал вам что такое программирование и, если долго программировали, то должен был развить "алгоритмичный" склад ума=) Вообще советую начать погружение в Веб-программирование с клиентской части, чтобы понимать что хотите получить на выходе. Если интересно я начинал в таком порядке: HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL, JS - потом это все обрастает дополнительными знаниями технологий)

Comment: Ну я еще в универе изучил html и css.И продолжаю их изучать, так как понадобятся! А javascript начну скоро с книги Флэнагана.

Answer (score 1):

Учите php. На фрилансе 95% всех проектов это проекты написанные на php.  Изучите структуры и алгоритмы. Базы данных. Напишите пару проектов средней сложности для своего портфолио. Зная php без работы точно не останетесь.